# How to alter the sum value in knex

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, knex.js

How do I multiply the result value in Knex

```
   db.select().table('sales')
    .whereBetween('date-s', [req.params.startDate,req.params.endDate])
    .sum({totalSales:"sales-after-returns"})
    .avg({averageSales:"sales-after-returns"})
    .sum({sixtyPercentOfTotalSale:"sales-after-returns"} * 0.6)
    .then(result => res.json(result))
    })
```

the first two line is working fine ,I am not getting the third value **sixtyPercentOfTotalSale** ,how can I alter the sum of column ?

this is the error I'm getting in the console

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: value.toLowerCase is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the problem but this might work-- Just use knex.raw-

```
db.select().table('sales')
    .whereBetween('date-s', [req.params.startDate,req.params.endDate])
    .columns([
      knex.raw('sum(sales-after-returns) as totalSales'),
      knex.raw('avg(sales-after-returns) as averageSales'),
      knex.raw('sum(sales-after-returns * 0.6) as sixtyPercentOfTotalSale'),
     ])
    .then(result => res.json(result))
    })
```